# Exclude beans in @WebMvcTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If I have a main like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyMain implements CommandLineRunner
{

   @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(MyMain.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args)
    {
        myService.doSomething();
    }
}
```

I have some @RestControllers annotated classes. And to test them with @WebMvcTest annotated classes, I have to add into these test classes the following:

```
@MockBean
private MyService myService;
```

I am not using this service so, do I have to add this in all @WebMvcTest annotated classes or there is a better way to do it?

I have the same problem with the following bean too:

```
@MockBean
private SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be "adding these mockbeans in every WebMvcTest", you can create an annotation, then annotate all your `@WebMvcTest`-annotated classes with it.

For example:

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
@MockBean(UserService.class)
@Import({WebSecurityConfiguration.class,
        UserServiceConverter.class,
        AuthorizationFacade.class
})
@WithMockUserWithAuthority
public @interface SpringBootControllerTest {
}
```

Another thing you can do is restrict the beans that Spring will be injecting once you annotate your test class with `@WebMvcTest`, by using the `controllers` option of `@WebMvcTest`. For example:
`@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyRestController.class)`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should decide if you are going to use the annotation in function of what are you trying to accomplish.

Being more clear: if you want to create a test that performs an http request then you should use @WebMvcTest due to the auto-configuration of useful stuff like spring security and MockMvc ([official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html)).

If you just want to test a specific method without the http part, then you probably don't need it.

In summary: the decision about use (or not use) the annotation, would be related with the kind of test you want to perform and not with the dependence you have.

Comment: In fact, I am using WebMvcTest and MockMvc, but if I do not add those Mockbeans, the tests do not work because a failure in the context

Comment: Yes, of course, you want to instantiate a controller that depends on a service. I think you should use the @MockBean. What im trying to say is that this is not a problem of the @MockMvcTest annotation. 

But now, if I understand your question correctly, you want to know what is the difference between testing a method that use a service with one that doesnt use it. And the difference is that where you use the service you will have something like:
`given(this.myService.method(...)).willReturn(...);` 
And you are not going to have it in the the test where the method doesnt use the service.

Comment: What I am asking if is there is any way to create a parent class for all controllers in which we can configure something instead of adding these mockbeans in every WebMvcTest. Or if we can create an specific configuration, profile or whatever to avoid this